# What is the most effective model to use in terms of representing game characters and/or sprites?

Tags: database-design, mongodb, cocos2d-iphone

I am in the process of designing an RPG style game however in terms of storing data wanted to use a database modeling/system that would make the most sense.

Some of the choices I have our:

- Class relational database (Old school queries)
- Classic relational using ORM (doctrine 2?)
- NoSQL/schema less database(No Joins)

In my mind I was thinking that ORM would make the most sense since you can deal with game objects and they can be mapped by database objects. However I am open to opinions and practices that existing game developers have used.

I would appreciate feedback in this matter.

Comment: back when I was coding games and last time I checked Real-World [TM] games did definitely **NOT** ship with embedded SQL DBs.  Is your RPG single player or online?  If it's online, is there a centralized server or shall it be peer-to-peer?  In any case, sprites are nearly **ALWAYS** rendered on the client-side and there's no SQL involved in typical game clients.

Comment: RPG will be online. It will have a central server.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r I doubt somebody would pick PHP (hinted at by Doctrine 2) if it weren't to be played online ;)

Comment: @Marius Burz: does change a yota my comment: sprites/gfx are nearly always rendered on the client-side and game don't ship with SQL (nor embedded SQL) DBs.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r And of course there are only sprites/gfx and sounds in a game. There is no state nor any other data that needs to be persisted. Roger that, sir!

Comment: @Marius Burz: dude... I've been working professionally in the game industry.  The **QUESTION's TITLE** specifically mentions game characters and sprites.  Need backup, sir!

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r I trust the OP more than your experience. If he's after a persistence solution that involves databases, there must be a reason, especially for persisting characters' data that can change over time. No offense, but do you think you know better what he needs than he does? How would you save the data for millions of characters? An array in a TXT file? Cookies in the browser? Maybe the key here is "you've been", and maybe the times just changed and in big online games everything is done in a different way than you're accustomed to. Maybe, sir.

Comment: @Marius Burz: you realize what you just wrote?  You wrote: "maybe the key here is *"you've been"*?   Check my SO profile and rep: check the *questions* I have asked here and how many people upvoted and favorited them and check the answers I gave.  That's the nice thing with SO: you can see who's who and I'm not impressed by your profile.  I have something else to add: I don't know many RPGs written in PHPs and I'm not exactly sure PHP would be the best server-side choice to write a RPG.  I do realize you may not like this comment seen that PHP seems to be your only area of expertise ; )

Comment: Don't feed the troll... don't feed the troll.

Comment: Guys, I appreciate feedback from both of you :).  Let's all relax and move on :)

Comment: On a side note, someone down-voted 4 of my answers on different threads for no reason.

Comment: Well, someone downvoted 9 of my answers, for whatever the reason. I wonder who that could be, not! Such are some folks.

Comment: Amazing stuff alright. Sorry about this. I really did not mean to cause harm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the best performance I would go with DAO classes, plain old queries and specialized data objects that suit the best what you need. Could become very complex to handle, but you have the control over everything. You can map game objects to database objects and vice-versa by using Mapper classes.

An ORM is much easier to use but it loses when it comes to performance and flexibility to do special things (targeted queries with joins and other things like this). I'd also choose them if your team is not very experienced developing database driven applications without ORM.

NoSQL might be a good option too, but you details are not enough to further comment on it especially since it has quite some advantages/disadvantages when compared to relational databases. It's a matter of do the advantages outweigh the disadvantages in you specific case.